# Unable to connect to mongo db hosted in aws

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am unable to connect with mongo db hosted in aws. i am succesfully able to ssh but not able to connect with mongo db. can some one please guide me thanks.

JSch jsch = new JSch();

```
Session session = null;
String username = "name";
String host = "ec2.amazonaws.com";
int port = 22;
String privateKeyPath = "./src/";

jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyPath);
session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

session.setConfig(config);

session.connect();
System.out.println("session connected.....");

System.setProperty("jdk.tls.trustNameService","true");
String connectionString = "mongodb://{userName}:{dbpassword}@dbcluster-***************.docdb.amazonaws.com:27018/?&retryWrites=false";

  MongoClientURI clientURI = new MongoClientURI(connectionString);
  MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientURI);

  MongoDatabase testDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("database-name");
  MongoCollection<Document> numbersCollection = testDB.getCollection("collection-name");
```

Comment: I am able to connect with database client but not through code. Kindly guide

Comment: Can you provide more input? Do you get an error, timeout, ssl handshake?